# my android app doesn't run on android studio after trying to activate the firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have completed the coding of my app, and when I tried to configure the firebase for my app by editing the two build.gradle files and updating the android studio to the last version, the editor showed me this error after trying to synchronize my project :

Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.

[image: the image of error message]

Comment: you are probably missing an entry in your projects build.gradle for the right search locations of the repositories. Can you add your root/build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

And in project gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```